# Android: Reduce space between columns in GridView

Tags: android, android-layout

See attached screenshot where I am attempting to reduce the space between the columns in my GridView.

My main.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<GridView 
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
/>
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    <TextView
    android:text="@string/game_score"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am creating the ImageViews in my code from a Bitmap. However, I am not specifying any padding or spacing or otherwise.

How can I reduce this space between columns? I've tried a variety of settings on both GridViews and ImageViews but with no luck

Image is [image: here]:

Thanks

Comment: hey there, I'm having the same problem, and I was wondering if you found any solution; so did you?

Comment: Could you accept a solution specifying the number of columns instead of column width?

Answer (score 28):

try to fix the number of columns needed in xml file for grid and set stretchMode as columnwidth

```
android:numColumns="3"
android:columnWidth="60dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
```

or set the horizontal and vertical spacing in xml for grid

```
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
```

Comment: I actually had the numColumns already set in my code. None of these options reduced the space between the columns. Modifying the horizontal spacing to a negative value just pushed the overall grid more to the left. The only way I can get the space to disappear is to hardcode the width as follows: android:layout_width="350px". However, this is not my preferred solution

Answer (score 12):

Remove Gravity attribute and use the following mode

```
android:stretchMode="NONE"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*" - this does not seem to be an allowed attribute? Either way when I tried this with some of the valid attribute values it did not work

Comment: which represents * ( astrick ) means automatically it will adjust space

Comment: this just makes all the columns overlap. pretty weird behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Hi i had the same problem i solved by `mygridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);`

Answer (score 4):

Space between columns is because your gridview element is not completely occupying the column space provided by grid view.

The solution to remove space between columns is to measure the device's screen width and height and divide it by the number of columns and rows. This will give the width and height for each grid view element.

you have to assign this height and width to imageview and also scale your bitmap to match the imageview.

Code:

```
  DisplayMetrics displayMetrics=getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
  screen_width=displayMetrics.widthPixels;    //width of the device screen
  screen_height=displayMetrics.heightPixels;   //height of device screen

     int view_width=screen_width/number of columns;   //width for imageview
     int view_height=screen_height/number of rows;   //height for imageview


   Imageview myImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_id);
   myImageView.getLayoutParams().width=view_width;
   myImageView.getLayoutParams().height=view_height;

   Bitmap myImage=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, view_width, view_height, true);//scaling the image to match the size of image view
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I minimized column space by doing this

for gridView

```
android:numColumns="2"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="-30dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
```

for imageView

```
android:layout_width="115dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:padding="1dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginRight="-15dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issue of having slight horizontal spacing between the columns in few devices. ( I did not required any space. ) I was properly calculating the grid item width by dividing it with total width. I was getting this issue only on Lenovo devices.

following code was in activity related to grid.

```
int myRequestedColumnWidth = myGridViewContentMain.getRequestedColumnWidth();

Point size = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize( size );
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

int myGridColumns = width / myRequestedColumnWidth;

if ( myGridColumns == 0 || myGridColumns == 1 )
    myGridColumns = 2;
myColumnWidth = ( width / myGridColumns );

myGridViewContentMain.setNumColumns(myGridColumns);
```

following code was in layout xml for grid

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridViewContentMain"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:columnWidth="200dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutMainHeader"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayoutProgressBar"
    />
```

I was unable to solve issue after changing stretch mode values.

But following value in layout xml for GridView did the trick.

```
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
```

I hope, someone like me may find this helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you - like this:

[image: original]

For me, setting up the column width followed by forcing the stretch mode to `GridView.NO_STRETCH` worked.

XML:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/month_grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/giant_icon_bound_height"  <--
        android:numColumns="7"/>
```

Java:

```
binding.monthGrid.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
```

I've tried setting the stretch mode in the XML but it doesn't work for me. It seemed to me that somehow we must set it programmatically.

Now, if alignment problem shows up like this:

[image: old image]

(I've colored the GridView in red - and you can see the large amount of space on the right of all columns, although the spacing between all columns do disappear.)

Modify the java code as follows:

```
binding.monthGrid.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
binding.monthGrid.setLayoutParams(
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                binding.monthGrid.getRequestedColumnWidth() * 7,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
);
```

Here the `7` is my number of columns - `.getNumColumns()` sometimes don't work if the view is not initialized yet, so it'll be the best to have a variable keeping track of the number of columns you'll have for your GridView.

After fixing:

[image: new image]

**Other Methods**

As for my own experience, setting `android:horizontal_spacing` to a negative number do work, but it's a kinda bruteforce approach, in a sense that you'll have the columns either too close together or too far apart if your `android:horizontal_spacing` value is either too large or too small - which is not generalizable to a case where the view can be resized - In my case that I'm creating a custom view and brute forcing the value of `android:horizontal_spacing` don't work for every size of the view. Yet, if you find my first method not working, and your view have a fixed size, then setting `android:horizontal_spacing` to a negative value can still create a decent visual effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the space b/w column by setting the android:horizontalSpacing="-10dp" ( some negative number )