# Reduce Android GridView space between columns to 0

Tags: android, gridview, padding

I´m trying to reduce the space between the columns of my `GridView` to 0 to get the layout 100% filled with my items. At the moment I still having like a little padding at top and between the items. Right and left sides looks as I want.

Here is the code of my fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/movies_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/moviesGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/poster_width"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:textAlignment="center" />


</FrameLayout>
```

And this is the Activity_main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#E8F5E9"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
        app:menu="@menu/settings_header">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Finally this is  my dimens.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="poster_width">180dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="poster_height">280dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Here is how it looks right now:

[image]

I tried using

> android:stretchMode="NONE"

or just writing value 0 to every padding attribute, but it didn't work.

I also check this post to got what I have now, before it had a really big padding between every item:
[Android: Reduce space between columns in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425557/android-reduce-space-between-columns-in-gridview)

Comment: What is the layout of the grid items? You could try adding gridIItemView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0); in your adapter

Comment: Try using hierarchy viewer to determine which view / layout is adding the padding. It might be the items, not the gridview.

Comment: @Nikiole91 The layout of my items is "Fragment_main" . Its a customAdapter , I already tried adding the setPaddin in my adapter and it didnt worked.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman triedaswell, but items dont have any padding.:(